# "dotnet publish" (.net core) build step not working in visual studio team services with multiple projects

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, msbuild, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

We have a VS 2017 solution with one WCF-service project and one .net-core web-application targeting .net framework 4.5.2 and .net core 1.0 (1.0.0-preview2-003131).

By some reason I cannot get the website published through "dotnet publish"-command in visual studio team services.

The problem shows up in build step "dotnet publish", project is specified to match only the web-projects solution-file (**/InventoryIndexWeb.csproj) since I only want the web to be published in this build.

Gives the following errors:

- MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
- Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\3\s\WebSites\InventoryIndex\Staging\InventoryIndexWeb\InventoryIndexWeb.csproj

See screenshot for details:

[image: MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified, Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\3\s\WebSites\InventoryIndex\Staging\InventoryIndexWeb\InventoryIndexWeb.csproj]

Any suggestions how to solve this or workarounds? The plan is to push this to Octopus deploy as well when we get the publish step working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple projects / arguments to `dotnet publish`.

In your case you seem to have passed the artifacts folder as second argument. To do this, add `-o` before that directory:

```
dotnet publish your.csproj -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, now it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing to pass -o as parameter instead of only $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) did the trick as Martin stated above, and final configuration as below.

[image]